# min heap not working

Tags: java, algorithm, min-heap

I'm creating objects of arc type and insert it into heap which should sort them in ascending order but not working the output should be

```
(B A 4) (B C 8) (B H 11)
```

but it giving me this

```
(B A 4)  (B H 11)  (B C 8)
```

this is Arc class

```
public static class Arc implements Comparable<Arc> {

    /**
     * A vertex at one end of this arc.
     */
    Vertex v1;

    /**
     * A vertex at one end of this arc.
     */
    Vertex v2;

    /**
     * Weight assigned to this arc.
     */
    int weight;

    /**
     * Constructs a new Arc object from an existing edge in a graph.
     * 
     * @param v1 Vertex at one end of the edge.
     * @param v2 Vertex at the other end of the edge.
     * @param weight Weight of the edge.
     */
    public Arc(Vertex v1, Vertex v2, int weight) {
        this.v1 = v1;
        this.v2 = v2;
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o == null || !(o instanceof Arc)) {
            return false;
        }
        Arc other = (Arc)o;
        return weight == other.weight && 
                ((v1.name.equals(other.v1.name) && v2.name.equals(other.v2.name)) ||
                 (v1.name.equals(other.v2.name) && v2.name.equals(other.v1.name)));
    }

    /**
     * Compares the weight of this arc with that of another.
     * 
     * @param other Other arc
     * @return 0 if the weights are equal, +ve if this arc's weight is greater, -ve otherwise
     * 
     */
        @Override
    public int compareTo(Arc other) {
        return weight - other.weight;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
     */
        @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "(" + v1 + " " + v2 + " " + weight + ")";
    }
}
```

this is min heap class

```
public class MinHeap<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Iterable<T> {

    private ArrayList<T> items;

    /**
     * Constructs a new, empty heap with an initial capacity of 10
     */
    public MinHeap() {
        this(10);
    }


    public void siftUp(int k) {  // sift up starting at k
        while (k > 0) {
            int p = (k-1)/2;

            int c = items.get(k).compareTo((items.get(p)));
            if (c < 0) {
                T temp = items.get(k);
                items.set(k, items.get(p));
                items.set(p, temp);
                k = p;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Inserts an item into the heap.
     * 
     * @param item Item to insert.
     */
    public void insert(T item) {
        items.add(item);
        siftUp(items.size()-1);
    }


     /**
      * Returns (but does not remove) the min item in the heap.
      * 
      * @return Item at top of heap.
      * @throws NoSuchElementExcepton If heap is empty.
      */
    public T getMin() throws NoSuchElementException {
        if (items.isEmpty()) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
        return items.get(0);
    }

    public String toString() {
        String ret = "";
        for (T item: items) {
            ret += "  " + item;
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you have misunderstood the concept of min heaps.

A heap does not sort the elements, it's just a data structure that keeps the parent node smaller than it's children. This doesn't mean the elements are stored in sorted order in the heap. It does however mean that if you implement a method for removing the min element that also runs in `O(log(n))`, you can sort data in `O(n log(n))` by inserting every item into the heap and retrieving+removing them one by one, which results in them being returned in ascending order.